# Split screen just like Windows or Unity do

Tags: bash, debian, gnome, window-management

I'm looking in Debian wheezy for a way to split screen in two windows just like you can do in Ubuntu or Windows7/8.

I mean I'm used to select a window and push windowskey+left and select another one and windowskey+right, so I can take advantage of the 16:9 screen.

Is there any package or external app to do this in Debian wheezy with GNOME 3.4?

Answer (score 1):

I am now using Cinnamon which does this by default, just drag the window to the left and it maximizes to take up half the screen. Similarly to the top and right. Doesn't this work for Gnome? There should be a setting, look for "Edge snapping" or similar.

Anyway, before Cinnamon did this, I had written a little script that would do it for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

## If no side has been given, maximize the current window and exit
if [ ! $1 ]
then
    wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b toggle,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
    exit
fi

## If a side has been given, continue
side=$1;
## How many screens are there?
screens=`disper -l | grep -c display`
## Get screen dimensions
WIDTH=`xdpyinfo | grep 'dimensions:' | cut -f 2 -d ':' | cut -f 1 -d 'x'`;
HALF=$(($WIDTH/2));

## If we are running on one screen, snap to edge of screen
if [ $screens == '1' ]
then
    ## Snap to the left hand side
    if [ $side == 'l' ]
    then
        ## wmctrl format: gravity,posx,posy,width,height
    wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b add,maximized_vert && wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,0,0,$HALF,-1
    ## Snap to the right hand side
    else
    wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b add,maximized_vert && wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,$HALF,0,$HALF,-1 
    fi
## If we are running on two screens, snap to edge of right hand screen
## I use 1600 because I know it is the size of my laptop display
## and that it is not the same as that of my 2nd monitor.
else
    LAPTOP=1600; ## Change this as approrpiate for your setup.
    let "WIDTH-=LAPTOP";
    SCREEN=$LAPTOP;
    HALF=$(($WIDTH/2));
    if [ $side == 'l' ]
    then
        wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b add,maximized_vert && wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,$LAPTOP,0,$HALF,-1
    else
    let "SCREEN += HALF+2";
    wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b add,maximized_vert && wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,$SCREEN,0,$HALF,-1;
    fi
fi
```

It depends on `disper`, `wmctrl` and `xdpyinfo` all of which are available in the Debian repositories. It should work out of the box if you are only using one screen but may need to be tweaked (change the value of `$LAPTOP`) if you have 2 screens.

I then assigned two keyboard shortcuts, one for each of these commands:

1. Snap the current window to the left

   ```
   snap_windows.sh l
   ```
2. Snap the current window to the right

   ```
    snap_windows.sh r
   ```

I could then run the appropriate keyboard shortcut to get the desired effect. This should work but there is almost certainly a setting for this in Gnome.

Comment: Thanks, but in fact I already programmed a similar script which also depends on wmctrl (but hardcoded coordinates), but Im asking for an already proved package/software

Comment: Well anyway, I'll give a try to your script which seems more advanced than mine =)